# Sitecore connector for Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Our current website is built with **Wordpress** CMS & uses **Amazon S3** for images,css & js etc.

Now we are moving this site to **Sitecore 7.2** & want to utilize the **Amazon S3** for all our images,css & js etc.,so

**Is there any connector/module for Sitecore to Amazon S3?**

I did some research & found a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xFrpBH5Dkw) on you tube for **"Amazon AWS CloudFront Sitecore Integration"**,but this module is not available on **[Market Place](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#qr=CloudFront)**.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the CDN Connector which was listed on the Sitecore Marketplace [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_CDN_Connector.aspx)

Unfortunately this is not working with Sitecore 7.2.

However in this [blog post](http://sitecorecode.com/index.php/tag/amazon-cdn-connector/) it is explained how to run in in 7.2.The solution is basically replacing the Sitecore.Kernel.dll and the HtmlAgilityPack.dll and recompiling it again.  If you are not happy with the solution provided there you can always modify the code yourself. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/NTTDATA/SitecoreCDN)

Comment: Thanks for this,one question-Does this module upload content to Amazon S3,when we upload media to Sitecore?

Comment: @Vikram I personally never used the module, but as it seems it is uploading them runtime judging by the help pdf - http://nttdatasitecore.com/~/media/Files/NTTDATASitecoreCDNConnector.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately this module does not work with the **Amazon S3**